# Introduction to Probability Chapter 1 Problem 13.a

Tags: probability, set-theory

I am learning Probability using the book Introduction to Probability, and solving the end of chapter problems. I am not sure I fully understand the question from Chapter 1. (13.a)

###### Problem Statement

Let $A_1$, $A_2$, be an infinite sequence of events, which is "monotonically increas­ing", meaning that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for every $n$. Let $A = \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Show that $P(A) = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} P(A_n)$. *Hint*: Express the event A as a union of countably many disjoint sets.

###### My Question

What I am a bit confused about is, if the set is monotonically increasing, shouldn't $A = \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ simply become $A_n$, since $A_i$ for all $i < n$ is contained within $A_n$? Isn't it obvious in that case, that, $P(A) = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} P(A_n)$? What purpose is the hint serving, I am not sure. Thank you.

Comment: $\cup_{k=1}^{n} A_k=A_n$ but $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$ need not be any of the sets $A_n$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for your comment. Can you please point me in the right direction where I can read more about this? Thanks.